# Azure Active Directory - Get Authorization for Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization

I'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user in the hope of calling Microsoft Graph Api from my web app. On section 2 of the article it explains how to get the auth code which is required for making the request to get the access token ...

Can someone please advise where I get the 'code' from as part of the request in part 2? I was expecting this to be returned in the redirect URL as a query string param, but this is not the case.

Thanks,

**Edit**

I have opted against using MSAL becuase of the bugs I have encountered when using the library. Instead my configartion is the following;

**Startup.cs**

```
         JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var userAuthenticationTicketRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IUserAuthenticationTicketRepositoryWrapper>();
        var configSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigSettings>();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAd(options => configuration.Bind("Config:AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.SessionStore =
                    new AuthenticationTicketStore(userAuthenticationTicketRepository, configSettings);
            });
```

Implementation of **AddAzureAd**

```
 public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureADOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureOidcOptions>();

        builder.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("Account/AccessDenied");

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };

        });

        return builder;
    }
```

**ConfigureOidcOptions**

```
 public class ConfigureOidcOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    private readonly AzureADOptions _azureOptions;

    public ConfigureOidcOptions(IOptions<AzureADOptions> azureOptions)
    {
        _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
    }

    public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = _azureOptions.ClientSecret;
        options.Authority = new Uri(new Uri(_azureOptions.Instance), _azureOptions.TenantId).ToString();
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    }

    public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you [should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user#authorization-response) get the `code` as a query param of the redirect URL. If you are not getting it, you should get an `error` parameter. Anyway, it would be good to post your auth request and the response URL you are getting.

Comment: Am I right thinking the 'authorization' step is when I am prompted to sign into my web app. I'm not getting the 'code' param, but I'm also not getting an error. How can I post my auth request?

Comment: Edit the question and add your auth request URL and a response URL (you can mask client_id param value if you don't want to make it public). By the authorization step, they probably mean that the client (your application) gets authorized by a user (resource owner) to use the resource (MS Graph API) on the user's behalf - OAuth2 is an access delegation protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The Authorization request should be

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access user.read mail.read
&state=12345
```

Replace the **tenant** and **client_id** with your value. And the **redirect_uri** should be consistent with the one in the portal.

[image]

When you request the url in the browser, you will be asked for logging in. After that, you will get the code parameter in the url.

[image]

Comment: At one point in code do I make the call to the authorize endpoint. Isn't this taken control of when I add the 'Authorize' attribute to my MVC controllers?

Comment: @japesSophey If you are using adal or msal, of course it is taken control.

Comment: @japesSophey You can take a look at this sample. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph

Comment: Hi opted against using msal becuase of bugs I encountered. I've updated my questions with my code snippet.

Comment: @japesSophey Now your issue is how to use adal to get access token to access graph api?

Comment: yes, I basically want to know how I obtain an auth code to get a access token

Comment: @japesSophey Take a look at this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/archived/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UserProfileController.cs

Comment: @japesSophey Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: In the end I've gone with using MSAL to help deal with my complexity of micro services and multi node. However, I'm already experience bugs with MSAL :(